# Unable to create Node Group in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I have a public and private EKS cluster . I'm using existing VPC where our most of ec2s are created using , so I have created the cluster in existing VPC.

I'm getting below issues while creating Node Group in this cluster. I have used Runbook to get these results.

Regarding first warning below , I have checked my End policy and they have full access.

Regarding error, I have followed the link for the resolution and updated ConfigMap to reflect correct arn like arn:aws:iam::547123871192:role/AmazonEksNodeRole. Even after updating arn correctly I'm still getting this error.

Can anyone help me identifying the issue.

HERE IS A SUMMARY OF THE ITEMS THAT REQUIRE YOUR ATTENTION:

**[WARNING]**: The default VPC Endpoint Policy is not being used. Please ensure that the worker node is able to communicate with the VPC Endpoint.

**[ERROR]**: IAM role arn:aws:iam::547123871192:role/MyCloud/AmazonEksNodeRole has an unsupported character "/" in its name. Please review this URL for further details: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/issues/268

**[WARNING]**: No secondary private IP addresses are assigned to worker node i-05315d2ce3b8ceab2, ensure that the CNI plugin is running properly. Please review this URL for further details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html

**[WARNING]**: As SSM agent is not reachable on worker node, this document did not check the status of Containerd, Docker and Kubelet daemons. Ensure that required daemons (containerd, docker, kubelet) are running on the worker node using command "systemctl status ".

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add NAT gateway to public subnet of your VPC and add a route at corrsponding route table for public subnet. This should help.